# Determining $P(x_1<x_2<x_3)$ when a pdf is given

Tags: probability

> Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be a random sample from a discrete distribution with probability function
>
> $g(x)=\frac{x}{10}$ for $x=1,2,3,4$
>
> $g(x)=0$ otherwise
>
> What is the probability $P(x_1<x_2<x_3)$?

I am assuming that $\frac{x}{10}$ is the probability of $x$ being selected. Hence, there are four non zero possibilities: $1-2-3, 1-2-4, 1-3-4, 2-3-4$

The sum of probabilities of these is $\frac{6+8+12+24}{1000}=\frac{1}{20}$

I was told this was completely wrong, and that I had misunderstood the question. Any help would be great.

Comment: I'm assuming the variables are independent, is that right?

Comment: @bburGsamohT- Yes that is correct

Comment: Your calculation looks correct to me. Perhaps you could convince the person who told you it was wrong to elaborate a little it more...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right.   It *might* not be the method you were intended to employ, but your reasoning is sound and calculations are correct.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X_1 < X_2 < X_3) 
 & = \mathsf P(X_1<2)\mathsf P(X_2=2)\mathsf P(X_3>2) + \mathsf P(X_1<3)\mathsf P(X_2=3)\mathsf P(X_3>3)
\\[1ex] & = g(1)\,g(2)\,\big(g(3)+g(4)\big)+\big(g(1)+g(2)\big)\,g(3)\,g(4)
\\[1ex] & = \frac 1{10}\,\frac{2}{10}\,\frac{3+4}{10}+\frac{1+2}{10}\,\frac{3}{10}\,\frac{4}{10}
\\[1ex] & =\frac{1}{20}
\end{align}$$

---

PS: Just in case you misinterpreted the inequality signs or something:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X_1 \leq X_2 \leq X_3) 
 & = \sum_{x_2=1}^4 g(x_2)\,\Big(\sum_{x_1=1}^{x_2}\,g(x_1)\Big)\,\Big(\sum_{x_3=x_2}^4 g(x_3)\Big)
\\[1ex] & \vdots
\\[1ex] & =\frac{7}{20}
\end{align}$$